# Change workspace causing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest

Tags: java, web-services, rest, rad

I have created a new workspace and loaded projects from repository.

Published project to web Sphere, when I try to test a REST web service, im getting following exception(for all the services in the project).
same code worked fine when I publish it from old workspace.
(same server instance in both the workspaces)

```
RequestProces E org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor
handleRequest An unhandled exception occurred which will be propagated
to the container. [12/11/13 18:10:27:002 IST] 00000025 servlet       E
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0014E:
Uncaught service() exception root cause JAX-RS Servlet:
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest   at
org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:195)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:124)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)     at
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1147)
    at
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:722)
    at
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:449)
    at
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1020)
    at
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:886)
    at
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1655)
    at
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
    at
com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at
com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at
com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at
com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at
com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)     at
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)     at
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)     at
com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1650) Caused by:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest   at
java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)   at
java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:77)   at
java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:139)  at
com.ibm.acs.ibm.deliv.DeliverableManagerBTMT.loadDeliverable(DeliverableManagerBTMT.java:83)
    at
com.ibm.acs.model.DeliverableManager.myLoadDeliverable(DeliverableManager.java:1039)
    at
com.ibm.acs.model.DeliverableManager.getDeliverable(DeliverableManager.java:40)
    at com.ibm.acs.model.RequestHelper.getRequests(RequestHelper.java:62)
    at
com.ibm.acs.model.jaxrs.iface.AccessRequestREST.listRestartRequests(AccessRequestREST.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)     at
org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:183)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:110)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodWADLHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodWADLHandler.java:51)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:52)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
    at
org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
    ... 25 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest   at
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)  at
com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:198)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:646)    at
com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:113)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:612)    at
com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
    at
com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have missed to package `httpclient-XX` libraries . Verify your (webroot)\ WEB-INF\lib of new war file contains this jar file

Comment: code directly not using any httpclient-xx API, those jars were not there even before and it used to work

Answer (score 0):

RAD seems to be confused as to what classes are available to it. You might try removing the application from the server, restarting the server, and re-adding the application. Maybe even deleting the server and recreating it.

It doesn't seem like having the same Project and Server configured on multiple workspaces should cause any problems, but I'd guess some meta data somewhere is corrupted or confused. Like pointing to an old location or something.